# Enemy walks to the nearest player?

Tags: unity

I'm trying making my enemy goes to the nearest player to him but what i get is kind of hesitated or shaking. I think is from the first line on Update but i don't know how to solve it. Here is my script

```
private Animator enemy_anim;
private NavMeshAgent mAgent;
private GameObject[] player;
public GameObject[] dead_point;
public int farPoint, dead_point_number,player_number;
public float dist;
public bool enemt_run, enemy_atack = false;

void Start()
{
    mAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    enemy_anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    dead_point = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("dead_point"); // 3 points
    enemy_dirction();

}

void Update()
{
    player_number = Random.Range(0,player.Length);
    dead_point_number = dead_point.Length;
    dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player[player_number].transform.position);


    if (player != null && dist <= 5.1f)
    {
        mAgent.destination = player[player_number].transform.position;
        if (dist < 1.2f)
        {
            enemy_atack = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy_atack = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (dead_point_number > 0)
        {
            mAgent.destination = dead_point[farPoint].transform.position;
        }
        else
        {
            mAgent.destination = player[player_number].transform.position;

        }
        if (mAgent.remainingDistance <= 1.5f)
        {
            enemy_atack = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy_atack = false;
            enemt_run = true;

        }
    }

    mAgent.speed = 1.0f;


    enemy_anim.SetBool("run", enemt_run);
    enemy_anim.SetBool("attack", enemy_atack);
}// end update


void enemy_dirction()
{
    if (dead_point_number > 0)
    {
        farPoint = Random.Range(0, dead_point.Length);
        mAgent.destination = dead_point[farPoint].transform.position;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Rollbacked your edit because tagging your question `[Solved]` is not something we do on this site. Answering is encouraged even though a question is answered and people can see if a question is accepted or not by looking at the color of the "answers" number box anyways :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Update(), which is once per frame, you pick a new target with `player_number = Random.Range(0,player.Length);`, and if it's closer than 5.1 or if there are no dead_points, you steer towards it.

This means that if you are within 5.1 units of multiple enemies or if there are no dead_points, you bounce randomly between different targets every frame, causing a jitter.

You should only update `player_number` if:

1. you currently have no target and there is a close by target
2. OR your target becomes invalid, i.e. it died, it moved too far away, etc.

---

Edit: pick closest enemy each frame (still a suboptimal strategy, but it should eliminate the jittering)

```
player_number = 0;
for(int i=1; i<player.Length; i++) {
   if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player[i].transform.position) <
       Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player[player_number].transform.position)) {
       player_number = i;  
   }
}
```

Comment: You right but if i change these things other scripts need to change. Can I make enemy read the distance of the closet player and chose him rather than random.range ?

Comment: you could, edited answer